# Can someone carry me through the process of sketching $f(x, y) = (x^2 + 1)(y^2 -1)$

Tags: calculus

The level lines are for $f(x,y) = (-2,-1,0,1,2)$. I've always struggled with this and I usually just do it with software, but I'd like to know your reasoning behind drawing this by hand

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFbQT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x^2+1)(y^2-1)=2$ is a curve in the plane $z=2$ whose equation can be written as
$$y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{x^2+3}{x^2+1}}$$
Let's consider the positive one, the other one is the symmetric wrt the $x$-axis
$$y=\sqrt{\frac{x^2+3}{x^2+1}}$$
It is an even function, symmetric wrt $y$-axis

$$\underset{x\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\sqrt{\frac{x^2+3}{x^2+1}}=1$$
Which means there is an horizontal asymptote $y=1$

$$y'=-\frac{2 x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^{3/2} \sqrt{x^2+3}}$$

$y'=0$ for $x=0$ and $y=\sqrt{3}$. It's a maximum because $y'<0$ for $x>0$ and $y'>0$ for $x<0$.

These informations are enough to plot the graph below

[image]

setting $1,0,-1,-2$ you get the others. The level curves are the sections of the surface $f(x,y)=(x^2+1)(y^2-1)$ with a plane $z=k$

[image]

Comment: How did you get the first graph? I don't understand how to do that by hand

Comment: @jordi Plot $$y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{x^2+3}{x^2+1}}$$

Comment: I don't get the intuition to do it on paper without needing software (I could do it programming but that's not what I want to know). What is the idea behind plotting that?, is there a method? What I don't understand is the process of going from that formula to the plot.

Comment: @jordi It's not an "intuition". I edited my answer to include the steps to plot manually the graph.